# Issue concatenating two strings containing '&' in dart

Tags: string, dart

I have a code like this :

```
// Language = Dart

var someVariable = 'Hello';
var someOtherVariable = 'World';
var str = 'somedomain?x=${someVariable}&y=${someOtherVariable}';
return str;

// Expected:
// somedomain?x=Hello&y=World;
// Actual
// somedomain?x=Hello
```

If I replace the `&` character with any alphabets, it is able to successfully concatenate. What am I doing wrong.

This is the actual code which I used in FlutterFlow, and am having issues with:

```
Future<String> getEventUrlFromReference(BuildContext context, DocumentReference? eventReference) async {
  var userId = currentUser?.uid as String;
  return "https://somedomain.com/event?eventReference=${eventReference?.id}" + "&invitedBy="+userId;
}
```

// result: https://somedomain.com/event?eventReference=referencevalue

Comment: what is printf?

Comment: Please provide code that you've actually verified can reproduce the problem.  The above code has a typo (`printf` instead of `print`), and after correcting it, the output I observe matches the output you expect.  Whatever problem you're encountering, it's almost certainly not with the string concatenation itself and is coming from some other source.

Comment: Also be sure to check out [Uri.encodeComponent()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.5/dart-core/Uri/encodeComponent.html).

Comment: I used this snippet of code inside FlutterFlow custom actions. It could be probably be an issue there..

Answer (score 0):

This was a string encoding issue. I was using the result of my function/code as body text in `sms://<number>?&body=<string_containigng_&_character>`; The text which is appended to the sms text truncates at the `&` character, and I made a mistake assuming it's a string concatenation issue.

Comment: I would suggest just deleting your question.  Since the premise of your question is wrong and since the solution is unrelated, it's very unlikely that it will ever help anyone else.